# SQL Insert IP as Unique ID (not working completely)

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem to register all IP-addresses from the visitors with a Unique Key made from their IP-address...

I see also that some visitors have a different Unique Key made from their IP-address... To get a Unique Key I use str_replace from the IP-address
 but some str_replace gives different numbers than their IP-address

I saw in another table what register all IP-addresses without a Unique Key,
that some visitors are not registered in the table with Unique Key made from their IP-address.

I hope anyone has tips how to register all IP-addresses with a Unique-Key made from their IP-Addresses ???

I am using this PHP code

```
<?php

 $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 $today = date("Y-m-d-H.i.s");
 $intip = str_replace(".","",$ip);
 $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
 echo $details->country; // -> "US"
 ?>
```

& This is the SQL INSERT INTO code

```
 mysqli_query($con," INSERT INTO ip_register (id,ip_adress,country,date) 
 VALUES ('$intip','$ip','$details->country','$today') ON DUPLICATE KEY 
 UPDATE ip_adress ='$ip' ");
```

Comment: Learn to use query parameters.  Don't munge query strings with constant values.

Comment: Just removing the dot may cause clashes - consider 82.11.5.6 and 82.1.15.6.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for removing the decimal points from the IP addresses:

```
$intip = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $ip );
```

IP address is not a unique value for a database Unique Key. There might be different users on the same IP address. These will not be added to the database if they have the same IP.

For the SQL query this might be causing a problem:

```
$details->country;
```

Add this variable before the SQL query:

```
$country = $details->country;
```

Then in your SQL query:

```
VALUES ('$intip','$ip','$country','$today')
```

Your SQL statement has a **MASSIVE SECURITY HOLE**, it is open to [SQL Injection](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/), learn how to use [PDO](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) or [Prepared Statements](https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection) to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: Grant... thanks for the tip I gonna try it out... + Thanks for the warning I will in the future convert everything to PDO (what I a little understand)

Comment: Due to privacy issues which might come up it would be more secure to only saved a hashed ip in database. I'd suggest ```hash('sha256', $ip)``` insted of preg_replace.

Comment: @AndyRosslau - Agreed, I don't know what the OP wants to do with the IP's but he can't get the original value back from a HASH